# "normal sleep","good night's sleep" or "night's sleep"

Tags: word-choice

> Given sentence:
>
> Researchers  say  that  normal  people  may  have  four  or  five  REM  periods  of  dreaming  a night.
>
> Question:
>
> Four or five REM periods of dreaming take place during a ................ sleep.
>
> Possible answers:
>
> 1. normal
> 2. night's
> 3. good night's sleep

In my personal opinion, I will go for No.2#.
I think the word "normal" is only for "people" in the given sentence . The word "good night's sleep" is more natural, but the word "good" is not used in the given sentence.So I prefer No.2# to others.

Please share your possible answers with  me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. BTW, the comma in the Given Sentence is wrong (leave it out).

Answer (score 1):

They're all acceptable. 3 is preferable. If you use 1, I would add "session", as in "during a normal sleep session." Sounds more idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1):

Research has shown that REM sleep helps the body refresh itself and sleep without REM is less restful, therefore

> a good night's sleep

would be the appropriate phrasing since sleep may occur without REM and the meaning of "a good night's sleep" implies a restful sleep.

Your first sentence only speaks to "normal" people but not the type of sleep they may have.

Comment: It is #3 that I am saying is the appropriate answer.  #2 may or may not be with REM sleep.